# How to create an array of List<int> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list

I have a problem where I need an array of arrayList.

For example if we take an Array of ArrayList of int, it will be like:

```
int[]<List> myData = new int[2]<List>;

myData[0] = new List<int>();
myData[0].Add(1);
myData[0].Add(2);
myData[0].Add(3);


myData[1] = new List<int>();
myData[1].Add(4);
myData[1].Add(5);
myData[1].Add(6);

myData[0].Add(7);
```

How can we implement a datastructure like the above in C#?

In C, its like a array of LinkedList. How can I do the same in C#?

Comment: The example is not an array of `ArrayList`.

Comment: `int[]<List>` makes no sense sintactically. Maybe you want `List<int>[]`?

Comment: for your next question concerning C#, I would recommend to tag it with C#, because otherwise people may not find it.

Comment: I know that the syntax is not supported in C# hence the question - How to do it in a different way. Thanks for C# tag recommendation. I will surely remember it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var myData = new List<int>[]
{
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
    new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Qrystal, This is the solution I needed.

Comment: You don't need "List<int>" --    

    var myData = new[]
                {
                    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
                    new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 }
                };

Answer (score 10):

Almost as you tried, only the first line is incorrect:

```
List<int>[] myData = new List<int>[2];
myData[0] = new List<int>();
myData[0].Add(1);
myData[0].Add(2);
myData[0].Add(3);


myData[1] = new List<int>();
myData[1].Add(4);
myData[1].Add(5);
myData[1].Add(6);

myData[0].Add(7);
```

Thanks to madmik3, here is a link you can read something about generic lists in C#:
[click me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Also, if you want to read something about arrays, e.g. the static copy method of the `Array` class, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) is some link for that.

Comment: This answer is right but the asker should also take a little time to earn more about Collections and Generics in C#. You will use the all the time so learning them will help a ton. You can start with list like above here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
var arraySize = 2;
var myArray = new List<Int32>[arraySize];


myArray[0] = new List<Int32>();
myArray[1] = new List<Int32>();
// And so on....

myArray[0].Add(5);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, This is the solution I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer lists but it's up to you...

```
List<List<int>> lst = new List<List<int>>();

lst.Add(new List<int>());
lst.Add(new List<int>());

lst[0].Add(1);
lst[1].Add(1);
lst[1].Add(2);
lst[0].Add(5);
```

Then if you really want a list at the end of it all use some linq.

```
lst.ToArray();
```

Comment: C# is case sensitive, and `List<T>` methods (like everything in the BCL) are PascalCased.

Comment: Bah, copy and paste typo. Thanks for fixing it

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to take the concrete type `List<int>` and make an array of it.
Just like `string` becomes `new string[2]`, so to `List<int>` becomes `new List<int>[2]`.

This will create an array which can hold two `List<int>`s.
However, each element in the array starts out `null`.
You'll need to put a `new List<int>()` into each slot of the array before using it.

---

However, you should probably use a `List<List<int>>` instead of an array of lists.