# C# Array of List Index out of bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I've made a program that extracts some info from a file , do some operations with it and store it back on a list.
Following this link:
[Are 2 dimensional Lists possible in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665299/are-2-dimensional-lists-possible-in-c)
I've been able to create a class with a list who would suit my needs. But after some debugging i've found that i was overwriting the list on each loop iteration. 
Then i decided to make an array of lists - followed this link:
[How to create an array of List<int> in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864557/how-to-create-an-array-of-listint-in-c)

Created an array of lists, initialized it and added elements. But when it needs to move to the next list position , it throws the out of boundaries exception.

I've tried a few things (readed about race condition) but none of 'em worked. 
The problem will happen only when i open more than one file with my code ; otherwise it works perfectly.

Exception is thrown at xmldata , in the last iteration of the current file. 
Ex: Selected two files, each one will add five elements. In the last element of the first file the exception will be thrown and there's data in the last element's position to be added.

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Exception thrown).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Code:

```
List<xmldata>[] finalcontent = new List<xmldata>[9999];
 finalcontent[listpos] = new List<xmldata>();//Initializing a list for each filename

                            foreach (Match m in matches)
                            {

                                Double[] numbers;
                                string aux;
                                aux = m.Groups[1].ToString();
                                aux = Regex.Replace(aux, @"\s+", "|");
                                string[] numbers_str = aux.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                numbers = new Double[numbers_str.Length];
                                for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
                                {
                                    numbers[j] = Double.Parse(numbers_str[j], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                    //Converts each number on the string to a Double number, store it in a position
                                    //in the Double array
                                    numbers[j] = numbers[j] / 100; //Needed calculus
                                    numbers[j] = Math.Round(numbers[j], 3); //Storing numbers rounded
                                }
                                string values = String.Join(" ", numbers.Select(f => f.ToString()));

                                if (i <= colors_str.Length)
                                {
                                    finalcontent[listpos].Add(new xmldata//The exception is thrown right here
                                    {
                                        colorname = colors_str[i],
                                        colorvalues = values,

                                    });//Closing list add declaration
                                 }//Closing if
                                i++;
                            }//Closing foreach loop
```

Link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwU9_GrFRYrTT0ZTS2dRMUhIWms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - you've posted a *lot* of code, but no stack trace, for starters...

Comment: I'll edit and leave only the needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the following:

```
if (i <= colors_str.Length)
```

to

```
if (i < colors_str.Length).
```

In fact I'm convinced that this is the problem.

This is because refereces begin at 0 and the last reference is length - 1, not length.

Comment: It worked. But i got onto another problem - after it add all elements to the current list position it'll like erase them all and start from position 0 again. Ex: finalcontent[0][0] = "Cyan" , "908098098098" - finalcontent[0][1] = "Magenta" , "8787978". In the next file's iteration it'll start from finalcontent[0][0] instead of finalcontent[1][0]

Comment: Okay. Looks like we're progressing. Post the code as it stands along with a stack trace as a new Question and we'll do our best to fix it.

Comment: My next problems seems to be regex capturing repeated groups(he shouldn't heh). I've searched and there's much information about that. I'll search \ read and if i don't find a solution i'll post a question. Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are fixed size, but Lists automatically resize as new items are added.

So instead, and since you're using Lists anyway, why not use a list of lists?

```
List<List<int>> ListOfListsOfInt = new List<List<int>>();
```

Then, if you really absolutely must have an array, then you can get one like this:

```
ListOfListsOfString.ToArray();
```

Comment: i've found that if i didn't used this array of lists, it would overwrite values i added previously in the next loop iteration. Lets say the code is running and i added values from a file. In the next iteration those values would be overwritten witht the new ones.

Comment: This usually happens when you're referencing the same List object in multiple places in your List-fo-Lists: By this I mean that if you change the contents of one List, then the changes fool you into thinking that they've happened in many places. Always make sure you're creating new Lists each time to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Convert non-ascii characters to .
for (int jx = 0; jx < cnt; ++jx)
if (line[jx] < 0x20 || line[jx] > 0x7f) line[jx] = (byte)'.';
```

This is a big example, but check this one.  You increase 'jx' before entering the statement, possibly exceeding the boundary of cnt?

Comment: I edided and added a comment where it throwns the error - just where i initialize a new xmldata list . This loop works okay didn't throw any problems , never. My exception is thrown at xmldata.

Comment: If i change (i <= colors_str.Length) to if (i < colors_str.Length) i'll lose the last position - and there's data on it.

Answer (score 0):

When using a list - it is better to use native functions for it.

```
List<xmldata>[] finalcontent = new List<xmldata>(); 
......
 finalcontent[listpos] = new List<xmldata>(); insted of   var _tmpVariable = new List<xmldata>();//Initializing a list for each filename
......
 _tmpVariable.Add(new xmldata
                                    {
                                        colorname = colors_str[i],
                                        colorvalues = values,

                                    });//Closing list add declaration

                    fs.Close();//closing current file
                    listpos++;//Increment list position counter
                    finalcontent.Add(_tmpVariable); // add list into list
```

As there is no exception details it is hard to get where the exception is thrown.
It could be a list issue, a string issue or other (even file reading issue as well),
So please update  this with current exception details.

Comment: I edited the main question and added where the exception is being thrown - also added some other details. Exception is thrown at xmldata , always , when adding the last element in the respective list position (based on a index). I can't do the way you suggested - if i do i'll be creating an new list instance everytime the if block executes .

Comment: so look @Knickerless-Noggins answer as it is probably closest to the source of exception (usualy you should get line number to pinpoint this issue.
Did you debug every step and check parameter values?
During deubg you will get exception when line is executed - then you can check it what exactly was wrong.

Comment: your solution didn't worked. I initialized the list the way you mentioned but i'm still getting the exception. One thing i've noted is that when it finishes adding the element the code goes adding elements again instead of going to read a new file.